# Is it possible to have an $a \times b \times c$ matrix?

Tags: matrices, definition

The book Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach states that a certain variable is a $2 \times 2 \times 2$ matrix", but I thought that matrices could only be rectangular (i.e. $a \times b$). Is it possible to have a matrix that is $a \times b \times c$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is such a generalisation. It's called tensor.

Comment: Is Wikipedia wrong on this, as it said that matrices are rectangular, implying they can't be a * b * c?

Comment: Matrix is a specific type of tensor which is always 2-dimensional. But there are 0-dimensional tensors (called scalars), 1-dimensional (vectors), and also 3-, 4-, and higher.

Comment: So I suppose the book is wrong then?

Comment: Yes, the book must have used wrong word.

Comment: A matrix is a rank-two tensor. Your book is right and so is the wikipedia entry. A matrix is always rectangular.